# Formview inside updatepanel not updating when triggered from button outside

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a formview inside an update panel but nothing happens:

```
<asp:Panel ID="uploadpanel" runat="server" CssClass="rightblock" Width="480px">
  <asp:UpdatePanel id="upnlGvAdmins" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
    <ContentTemplate>    
       <asp:FormView ID="fvPhpto" runat="server" DataKeyNames="id"
          Width="480px" AllowPaging="True"
          PagerSettings-Visible="false">
          <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("title") %>' runat="server" ID="descriptionLabel" />
            <asp:mageID="thumb1" runat="server" ImageSize="Large" PhotoID='<%# Eval("id") %>' />
            <asp:Label ID="noteslabel" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("notes") %>' />
          </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:FormView>
     </ContentTemplate>
     <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="UploadFile" />
     </Triggers>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>

   <h3>Upload Photo</h3>
   <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" CssClass="txtfield" />
   <div class="actionbuttons">
      <asp:LinkButtn ID="UploadFile" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="UploadFile_Click" />
    </div>
 </asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem today. `CommandName="Insert"` on the button wasn't sufficient and I couldn't get the form view to perform the update. The only way I could solve it was to either take off the update panel and suffer through full postback (boo!) or manually trigger the form view update using the `OnClick` event of my button. It's still not ideal, but it works.

So, in the aspx I have this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upMain" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Always">
<ContentTemplate>
           <asp:FormView runat="server" ID="fvNewForm" DataSourceID="dsoJobForm" DefaultMode="Insert">
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <h3>Create a new job form</h3>
                <div class="subSet">
                    Job Form ID: &nbsp;
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtJobFormID" MaxLength="10" Width="100"></asp:TextBox><br />
                    <br />
                    Job Form Name:<br />
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtJobFormName" MaxLength="50"></asp:TextBox><br />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSaveNewForm" CommandName="Insert" OnClick="TriggerFVUpdate" Text="Save & Continue" />
                </div>
            </InsertItemTemplate>

        </asp:FormView>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And in the code behind, I have this:

```
Protected Sub TriggerFVUpdate(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Me.fvNewForm.InsertItem(True)
End Sub
```

If anyone out there has a better solution, I'm totally up for it so let me know!